# How to add an existing sub-folder (with/without child files/folders) to the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory

The folder resides within my solution physical location but I can not find a command to add existing folder to the project from right-clicking. All I can see is "Add existing files". Trying to create the folder is denied since it already exists!

I tried to move the folder out of the solution folder on the hard disk, and add it again. Thing goes fine but it turns out to be awlful if the folder is a complex folder (with lots of files and folders inside). I gave up!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need "Include in project":

1. Click "Show all files", the small button at the head of your Solution Explorer, to show all files/folders of your solution. The ones not in your solution is in phantom/white color.
2. Right click your "existing folder" and select "Include in project"
3. Done

Hope that helps!

Comment: @sreimer What happened to you?