# Response.WriteFile from other aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Login.aspx page, and I wanna incude some piece of code in that page. I know I can do Response.WriteFile ("HelloMessage.aspx"), but if I simply do Project->New Item->Web Page, the GelloMessage.aspx page will be accesible throught Web browser. I wanna do this HelloMessage.aspx file unaccessible.
How to do this?

And question 2, can I keep aspx files in my custom folders?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @up OK, no more prefixes. I found answer to custom folders problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725923/1109215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can keep apsx files in subfolders. Those folders become part of the URL (as long as you don't add routing).

And you can block files using the `<authorize>` tag in web.config. Which could solve your fist problem (but to who would you allow access to Hello.aspx ?)

Every folder can has its own web.config. So, an easy example:

For all pages in the same folder as this config, deny access to anonymous users and allow access to all logged-in users:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
   <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Main folder is relative, if you mean where the homepage is then that is by default where it is. You can add routing to do all sorts of nonsense.

Comment: Example: I have 2 folders: 1) ASPX-Files 2) ASP-Project. Now how to tell VS to execute files from ASPX-Files folder? I dont wanna keep all files in one folder.

Comment: The main folder is simply the root folder of your app. And logged-in is according to the membership framework, you were writing a log-in page right? Make sure you use [Forms authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs).

Comment: Damn looks complicated, I just used if (Session["password"] == "secret") { Session["loggedIn"] = true; } that's all :P Dont't have any master page, forms authentication etc. So, I think i need to read more tutorials hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some markup that you'd like to include in several pages, then you should either use a user control, or perhaps a master page.